# Resources$NotFoundException for few Drawables on Vivo devices

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-resources

I am getting Resources$NotFoundException mostly on Vivo devices. This is only happening for Drawable resources. I have all variant from mdpi till xxxhdpi. All these are pngs. I am unable to replicate this and only getting this on production in 4 different places. 2 of which are in splash screen and 1 is in facebook login library on [this line](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/019c5018c293e61e1b5150ef10192085f968d85e/facebook-common/src/main/java/com/facebook/internal/WebDialog.java#L522) for [this drawable](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook-common/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/com_facebook_close.png). Which means these users are unable to enter the app. Any idea if there some special handling that need to be done for these devices? I have never faced something like this before.

sample code

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/splash"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_max="400dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/white_bg"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:src="@drawable/splash"/>
```

here I am getting this crash due to `splash` Drawable.

**Stack Trace**

> Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException Unable to
>   find resource ID #0x7f08013d
>   com.myapp.ui.splashScreen.SplashScreenActivity.onCreate
>
> Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to
>   find resource ID #0x7f08013d
>          at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getResourceName(ResourcesImpl.java:292)
>          at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:879)
>          at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:749)
>          at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:922)
>          at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawableForDensity(TypedArray.java:953)
>          at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:928)
>          at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:188)
>          at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:171)
>          at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.(AppCompatImageView.java:72)
>          at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.(AppCompatImageView.java:68)
>          at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:187)
>          at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:107)
>          at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1266)
>          at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1316)
>          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:817)
>          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:775)
>          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:908)
>          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:869)
>          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:521)
>          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
>          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
>          at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
>          at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:141)
>          at com.myapp.ui.splashScreen.SplashScreenActivity.onCreate(SplashScreenActivity.java:81)
>          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7129)
>          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7120)
>          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1220)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2906)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3031)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1732)
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:192)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6792)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
>          at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:826)

Comment: I think as you are not having that drawable in drawable folder it is giving you error

Comment: if you are adding drawable to different folders then it should be there in drawable folder too

Comment: @primo Are you saying apart from mdpi-xxxdpi folders. I also need to place my drawables in drawable folder as well? Is there a documentation that recommends this?

Comment: i dont know any document but I think it will solve your problem

Comment: @primo tried your answer. Did not work. Only vivo phones are showing this error.

Comment: what error you are getting. add your stack trace

Comment: and let you keep all your drawables in different folders according to their sizes

Comment: @primo added stacktrace.

Comment: " only getting this on production in 4 different places" - what does it mean exactly? Is it downloaded from Play Store? Or just a production build with signed APK?

Comment: @JánosSicz-Mesziár Its happening on play store build. By that I meant I have 4 different resources creating this issue, so I was getting 4 different crashes. But this one is the main one. It's only happening on Vivo phones.

Comment: Rest of them got solved when I use ImageView instead of AppCompatImageView. This one is still there even though I am now using ImageView for this one.

Comment: are you trying to set text to some `R.id.bla_bla_bla` on a EditText ? In that case, you should set text as a string .

Comment: there is no EditText on this screen. It is just a SplashScreen with images. @StavroXhardha

Comment: Could you export the APK from Vivo phone where issued? And drop into Studio and check resource is really packaged into downloaded APK file. One of new feature from Play Store to remove unnecessary resources from original APK. Currently this just an idea. But it can be progress to see what is in the download APK.

Comment: No one have a Vivo phone in my team. Only saw it on crashlytics. @JánosSicz-Mesziár

Comment: are you using VectorDrawables? The way to handle them on older devices changed a bit over the last few years, maybe thats the issue.

Comment: What is the Android version where issue occurred?
If you use `VectorDrawable` then for backward compatible try to load the image on this way: `AppCompatResources.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.your_vector_image);`
But I'm afraid this won't help with facebook image within SDK.

Comment: @ueen its a plain png. No vectors.

Comment: @Rishabh876  I am Facing same issue for vivo devices, is there any solution to handle this error ?

Comment: @Rishabh876 found anything ?

Comment: @wadali not yet. Still looking.

Comment: @Rishabh876 I am having the same issue. Is the bellow answer working? I am thinking at blocking on play store devices with such problems but I would only do it as a last resort.

Comment: @Adrian That solution did not work for me. What I did was, I loaded the drawable programatically. Also placed a ResourceNotFoundException catch. I don't know at the moment if that exception is ever thrown. But I am fine with it for now.

Comment: I putt all asset in drawable folder only. Removed from other asset folder like hdpi-drawable. Then it started working :D

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue for Vivo phones almost exclusively, I then added the image to a noDpi and that resolved it.